# Error: (0 , _reducers2.default) is not a function in my react-native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Following are my files for my react-native app:

**UserReducer.js**

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../actions/ActionConstants';

export default function UserReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {};
    case ActionTypes.LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**RootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserReducer from './UserReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: UserReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**index.js** in reducers folder

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './RootReducer';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    )
);
```

Running my app by react-native run-android. A default export for the UserReducer is giving me this error: **(0 , _reducers2.default) is not a function**

Comment: second argument of `createStore` should be the initial state

Answer (score 0):

Try this way(arrow function without function name):

```
import { ActionTypes } from '../actions/ActionConstants';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {};
    case ActionTypes.LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this is correct.